# Changing the Progress Event in .Net 6 web api

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I'm working on a file upload and want to show a progress bar in the UI.

The Controller works something like this:

```
1. public async Task Upload([FromForm] RequestModel request)
2.    fileService.save(request.file); // THIS CAN TAKE LONGER
3.    return Ok();
```

I'm using Angular as following:

```
this.http.post<ResponseModel>('ENDPOINT', formData, {
  reportProgress: true,
  observe: 'events',
});
```

That basically works, however the upload progress that is reported gets to 100% when the file is uploaded to the server successfully (into memory/tmp location) and when the execution is landing in **line 1.** it already reports 100%;

What I want is to be able to manipulate that Event so that **100% is just reported after line 2. (or 3.)** are finished.

I thought about creating another endpoint which can return an int (progress percentage) that is being set in the upload method however it would be much nicer if there is a way without it since it would mean less code and additionally I wouldn't have to juggle between the two numbers (upload to memory + new progress percentage variable).

**Is there a way to change the progress event in .Net?**

Something like this

```
 > REPORT PROGRESS but only until 60 % (because we still need to do something)
 public async Task Upload([FromForm] RequestModel request)
    > REPORT PROGRESS = "60 %"; // if necessary, 60 because we still need to save
    fileService.save(request.file); // THIS CAN TAKE LONGER
    > REPORT PROGRESS = "100%";
    return Ok();
```

Answer (score 0):

It reports upload progress (using XMLHttpRequest events), obviously upload is completed when controller action is reached.

You have to emulate 'correct' progress on UI, for example use multiplier 0.9 for progress events, so it will report 90% when upload is finished then add 10% when `this.http.post` call is finished.